# How to set Ajax Block Response with as left and content block in Magento

Tags: adminhtml, controllers, ajax

```
$myBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/admin_productqa_edit'); 

$myHtml =  $myBlock->toHtml(); 
$response['blck'] = $myHtml;
```

above code work perfect. I need Given below value return as ajax response from controller in magento. How to set ajax response in magento

```
$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/adminhtml_productqa_edit'));
$this->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/admin_productqa_edit_tabs'));
```

Please Give a perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

You can set ajax response like this:

```
    $response = array(
        'myblock'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/admin_productqa_edit')->toHtml()
    );

    $this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
```

You can't use `$this->_addContent` or `$this->_addLeft` when doing ajax call because you are not loading entire layout object. You are supposed to process the response and update DOM with javascript.